# Bootstrap dropdown menu with WTF and Flask

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I'm an amateur building a Flask/WTF/Jinja2 (using the Bootstrap) website, and I have not yet implemented a dropdown button.  Unfortunately, I'm really struggling with the Bootstrap / Jinja2 elements (i can get my data to the jinja2, but can't get anything to render properly).  If it helps as a reference, I'm emerging from the Corey Schafer school of Flask on Youtube.

Here is my WTF class statement:

```
class SegmentForm(FlaskForm):
     segmentID = SelectField(label='Choose a Segment', coerce=int, validators=[InputRequired])
```

Here is my route (Flask) statement:

```
@decks.route('/decks/segments', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def segments():
    form = SegmentForm()
    pathname = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

    df = pd.read_csv(pathname + '/upload_data/segment_summary.csv', index_col=None)
    form.segmentID.choices = df.seg_name
```

Where I am struggling is to get the Bootstrap / Jinja2 sorted out:

```
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id={{form.segmentID.label}}>
            {{ form.segmentID.label }}
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby={{form.segmentID.label}}>
                {% for segment in form.segmentID.choices %}
                  <option value="{{ segment }}">{{ segment }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What version of Bootstrap ? Your Jinja for loop is outputing `option` elements but the [Bootstrap 4 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#single-button-dropdowns) use regular `anchor` elements with an appropriate class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

form.py:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SubmitField, SelectField, SelectMultipleField, widgets
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, NumberRange, InputRequired, Length
 
class MultiCheckboxField(SelectMultipleField):
     widget = widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False)
     option_widget = widgets.CheckboxInput()

class FindSegmentForm(FlaskForm):
     submit = SubmitField('Identify Segment for Deck')
     clear = SubmitField('Reset to Blanks')
     cards = MultiCheckboxField('Select Cards for Deck', coerce=int)
```

From routes.py:

```
card_list = list(zip(df.card_id.to_list(), df.card_names.to_list()))
form.cards.choices = card_list
```

From display.html:

```
{% for cards in form.cards %}
    <div class="form-check">
        {{ cards(class="form-check-input") }}
        {{ cards.label(class="form-check-label") }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

My thanks to ectrimble for his original solution.
(https://gist.github.com/ectrimble20/468156763a1389a913089782ab0f272e)